# Which processes / services need to be running to perform a local sync with an iPod Touch iOS5 with Windows 7?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, wifi, windows

I'm running **Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit** and the wifi sync used to work properly, but due to lack of memory, I shut down some of the *processes / services* that would run automatically to make my computer run a bit faster.

Now I'd like to sync my **iPod Touch** with **iOS5** again but I don't know which services need to be turned on to sync again.

When I go to my iPod to sync, the button for wireless syncing in Settings isn't tappable.

Comment: Bonjour Serivce...

Comment: Apple Mobile Device Service...

Comment: Those seem to be it...for syncing over the wire...is there a specific port that it needs to run on, or do I need to have NetBIOS enabled or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here are the prerequisites for making this work over wifi:

## Prerequisites:

### Programs Running:

- iTunes

### Services Running:

*(Located in Start->Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services)*

- Bonjour Service
- Apple Mobile Device Service

### wifi:

- iPod connected to wifi and so is your computer

## iTunes Issues:

If you have all of the *prerequisites* above set, and on your iPod you enter *(Setting->General->iTunes Wi-Fi Sync)* and you find the **Sync Now** button is still disabled do the following:

1. In iTunes click *edit->preferences*
2. Click the **Devices** tab.
3. Click the **Reset History** button.

Now if you look at your iPod Touch again the **Sync Now** button should now be enabled.

(found in the [apple documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2690))

Answer (score 0):

I would add that simply downloading the latest iTunes installer, running it and choosing "Repair Installation" should re-enable whatever services you have disabled.